# Make Jquery Autocomplete or Select2 plugin work within knockout foreach binding

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, autocomplete

I'm having problems with autocompletes generated by knockout foreach binding.
Please have a look at the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/u05afbpp/1/

```
<table data-bind="foreach: cars" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
 <tr>
    <td>
        <span>Test</span>
        <input type="text" class="autocomplete"/>
    </td>
 </tr>
</table>

$(function() {
var availableTags = [
  "ActionScript",
  "AppleScript",
  "Asp",
  "BASIC",
  "C",
  "C++",
  "Clojure",
  "COBOL",
  "ColdFusion",
  "Erlang",
  "Fortran",
  "Groovy",
  "Haskell"
];
$(".autocomplete").autocomplete({
  source: availableTags
});
});

var viewModel = {
cars:ko.observableArray(),
myValue: ko.observable()
};
viewModel.cars.push("BMW");
viewModel.cars.push("Benz");
viewModel.cars.push("Renault");
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

What can I do to make it work?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the page starts rendering, there could be no elements with class .autocomplete. Is this what you want to have? http://jsfiddle.net/G_sh/u05afbpp/6/

I have moved the below code to ready function hoping it works.

```
var viewModel = {
cars:ko.observableArray(),
myValue: ko.observable()
};
viewModel.cars.push("BMW");
viewModel.cars.push("Benz");
viewModel.cars.push("Renault");
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```